# Windows Desktop Cordova App Crashing Instalty with no error messages

Tags: windows, cordova

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 RC to create a Cordova App, it works great on Windows Phone Device, Android Emulator and Device, iOS Ripple, but with Windows Desktop it just bombs out instantly with no indication of what went wrong.

Any idea how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is the known issue with the certificate required on Windows platform.

https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/11/11/cordova-certificate-issue-were-working-on-it/

You can download the right certificate from there and add it to your project.

Comment: I tried as suggested in the article and now an error is thrown in the javascript code for a barcode scanner plugin i'm using

Comment: require("cordova/windows8/commandProxy").add("BarcodeScanner", module.exports);

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: module cordova/windows8/commandProxy not found

Comment: I guess that is a different question then ;)